# How to edit value of an object using the reference?

Tags: javascript

I have a big object array `persons`

```
persons = [{name:'john1'}, {name:'john2'},...]
```

I iterated the array and found the object I am interested to edit

```
objectToEdit = persons .find((person)=>person.name==='john1')
```

Now I created an edited object in immutable way (`someOtherPerson = {name:'johnxx'}`)

```
objectFinal = {...objectToEdit, someOtherPerson}
```

Now I want to replace this `objectFinal` with  `objectToEdit` in `persons` array, without having to traverse the array again. But doing  `objectToEdit =objectFinal` , will just assign objectToEdited's reference to `objectToEdit` , without making any change in the `persons` array

Is there a clean way to achieve this without traversing the array?

**Edit**:

In this example, the object in persons jave just one key (i.e, `name`). This is to make question minimal. In my project, I have more than 30 keys.

Comment: what type is `someOtherPerson`?

Comment: `someOtherPerson = {name:"johnxx"}` as an example

Comment: an how should look like the result?

Comment: `{name:'john1'}` should be replace with `{name:"johnxx"} ` in `persons`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to edit an object in a list,in place, use Array.prototype.some

```js
var persons = [{
  name: 'john1'
}, {
  name: 'jack5'
}]

var someOtherPerson = {
name: 'johnxx'
}

persons.some(function(person) {
  // if condition, edit and return true
  if (person.name === 'john1') {
    // use Object.keys to copy properties
    Object.keys(someOtherPerson).forEach(function(key) {
      person[key] = someOtherPerson[key]
    })
    // or use assign to merge 2 objects
    Object.assign(person, someOtherPerson);
    return true // stops iteration
  }
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(persons))
```

Comment: Object.assign is what I was looking for. Can I say Object.assign is like destructuring operator but without losing reference? Also, I am wondering why did you suggest two other solutions which are not as clean as Object.assign(). Is there any advantage of using them over object.assign?

Comment: there is no advantage with other solutions. Object.assign will do what Object.keys does but in a single line.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid mutating the objects in the original array, you might use `.findIndex` instead, and reassign the item in the array at that index:

```js
const persons = [{name:'john1'}, {name:'john2'}];
const objectToEditIndex = persons.findIndex((person) => person.name === 'john1');
const someOtherPerson = {name:"johnxx"};
persons[objectToEditIndex] = {
  ...persons[objectToEditIndex],
  ...someOtherPerson
};
console.log(persons);
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this:

```
objectFinal = {...objectToEdit, someOtherPerson}
```

you lose the reference to the original `objectToEdit` object. To edit it, you can do

```
`objectToEdit.value = otherValue`.
```

PS: Having said that, you only lose reference to the first level object. If that object, contains another object or array, you **have** reference to it:

```
objectFinal.innerObject.value = otherValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

> {name:'john1'} should be replace with {name:"johnxx"} in persons

Reassign `persons` to the `persons`-array mapped with the new value:

```js
let persons = [{name:'john1'}, {name:'john2'}];
persons = persons.map( v => v.name === "john1" ? {name: "johnxx"} : v );
console.log(persons);
```

Or, if you're worried about performance, use [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) in combination with [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

> The findIndex method executes the callback function once for every
>   array index 0..length-1 (inclusive) in the array until it finds one
>   where callback returns a truthy value (a value that coerces to true).
>   *If such an element is found, findIndex **immediately** returns the index
>   for that iteration*.

```js
let persons = [{name:'john1'}, {name:'john2'}];
persons.splice(persons.findIndex( v => v.name==="john1" ), 1, {name:'johnxx'});
console.log(persons);
```

Or use a utility method (snippet for a large array (1,000,000 elements) and with performance timer)

```js
// replacer method
const replace = (obj, [key, value], replacement) => {
   obj.splice(persons.findIndex( v => v[key] === value ), 1, replacement);
   return obj;
}

// create a large array (this may take some extra time)
let persons = Array.from({length: 1000000}).map(v => 
  ({name: Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 1000000000).toString(16)}) );

// pick an entry
const someEntry = Math.floor(persons.length * Math.random());
const entry = Object.entries(persons[someEntry])[0];

console.log("before:", persons[someEntry]);
const t = performance.now();

// replacement call here
console.log("after:", replace(persons, entry, {name: "johnxx"})[someEntry]);
console.log("replacement took:", `${((performance.now() - t)/1000).toFixed(3)} sec`);
```